# Adding atspi-2 to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment table

Tags: programming, vala

I'm currently trying to learn Vala, but it fights me right from the start. I've basically copied the first Basic Sample found [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample).

I'm trying to build it using this command:

```
 valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 <filename>.vala
```

but I'm constantly getting this error message:

```
Package atspi-2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `atspi-2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'atspi-2', required by 'atk-bridge-2.0', not found
error: pkg-config exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I have no idea what any of this means nor how to fix this.

Comment: "Package 'atspi-2', required by 'atk-bridge-2.0', not found", a fast apt-cache search led me to gir1.2-atspi-2.0 . I have researched this issue but it might be worth trying:
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-atspi-2.0

In case of success I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the solution was installing `libatspi2.0-dev` using:

```
sudo apt-get install libatspi2.0-dev
```

This was all that I needed to do to stop receiving these errors. After that, everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug of pkgconf v0.9.4-1 (currently installed on Freya) that has been fixed in v0.9.5-1.

[Link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734491)

Comment: Okay, I read that report and saw a reference to `libatspi2.0-dev`. Judging by the description when it was reported, I just installed it and I'm not getting that error anymore.